# Moore–Penrose inverse definition as a vector form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, solution-verification, pseudoinverse

As an excercise I am trying to prove that $AA^{+}\vec{a}^{\,}_{i}=\vec{a}^{\,}_{i}$,
$\forall{i=1..n}$ is equal
to the more popular version $AA^{+}A=A$. I started by setting up a system of equations as follows:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      AA^{+}\vec{a}^{\,}_{1}=\vec{a}^{\,}_{1}\\
      \vdots\\
      AA^{+}\vec{a}^{\,}_{n}=\vec{a}^{\,}_{n}\\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

Then I turned it into a matrix form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
      AA^{+}\vec{a}^{\,}_{1}\\
      \vdots\\
      AA^{+}\vec{a}^{\,}_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
      \vec{a}^{\,}_{1}\\
      \vdots\\
      \vec{a}^{\,}_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
AA^{+}
\begin{bmatrix}
      \vec{a}^{\,}_{1}\\
      \vdots\\
      \vec{a}^{\,}_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
      \vec{a}^{\,}_{1}\\
      \vdots\\
      \vec{a}^{\,}_{n}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since $\vec{a}^{\,}_{i}$ is a column vector it has shape $(m\space x\space1)$ which seems to produce weird vector in the last equation. Is this part of a "proof" any good or is it a bad idea from the begining?

Comment: First of all, what are $a_i$?

Comment: i-th column of the A matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose $\vec{a}_j$ means the $j$-th column of $A$. Then $A$ is equal to $\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}_1&\cdots&\vec{a}_n\end{bmatrix}$. So, the correct identity should be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}AA^{+}\vec{a}_1&\cdots&AA^{+}\vec{a}_n\end{bmatrix}
=AA^{+}\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}_1&\cdots&\vec{a}_n\end{bmatrix}
=AA^+A=A
=\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}_1&\cdots&\vec{a}_n\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix-vector product $AA^{+}
\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}_1\\ \vdots\\\vec{a}_n\end{bmatrix}$ does not make sense because the size of $AA^+$ (which is, for example, $n\times n$ when $A$ is $n\times n$) does not match the size of the the column vector $\begin{bmatrix}\vec{a}_1\\ \vdots\\\vec{a}_n\end{bmatrix}$ (which is $n^2\times1$ in this example).

Comment: Yeah, that were my concerns about this solution. Thanks for resolving my issue :)